# Hypergeometric functions

Tags: math, julia, numeric

Does anyone know of a package to compute hypergeometric functions in Julia?

I have been using [GSL.jl](https://github.com/jiahao/GSL.jl) which is wrapper for the GNU Scientific Library, but GSL only supports 0F0, 0F1, 1F1, 2F0 and 2F1. I need to compute 3F2.

Comment: Have you tried `PyCall` with `SymPy`: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/hypergeometric.html?

Comment: @niczky12 nice, I can get it to work but I have not figured out how to get the actual number from the `PyObject` that is returned...

Comment: Never mind, I just have to `convert` it to a `Float64`. Thanks!!

Comment: For `SymPy.jl`, the `N` function can do that conversion with less typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `PyCall` module to use `mpmath` from Python (formerly part of SymPy `sympy.mpmath`):

```
# import mpmath module 
@pyimport mpmath as mpmath

x = mpmath.hyp3f2(1,2,3,4,5, 0.5)

# then you will need to convert this to a float
Float64(x)
```

Out:

```
1.189874754256423
```

Docs for `mpmath` and the available hypergeometric functions are here: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/hypergeometric.html

(If you don't have `mpmath` installed, you can install it with pip from the shell:)

```
pip install mpmath
```

Comment: I believe that mpmath is an independent Python package (no longer part of Sympy) since the 1.0 release of Sympy.